# Google Chrome: can't getElementById from chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, innertext

E.g., I'm trying to read the text of the element with id="tooltip" at https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction

The following code works fine from console:

```
var element = document.getElementById('tooltip');
if(element != null) {alert(element.innerText);}
else {alert("element contains null");}
```

Same code r**u**n from an extension shows "element contains null".

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener
(
  function(tab)
  {
    var element = document.getElementById('tooltip');
    if(element != null) {alert(element.innerText);}
    else {alert("element contains null");}
  }
);
```

And it's not surprising, because the **document** object contains the   *_generated_background_page.html*, and not my page in question. And the actual page I need seems to be contained in **tab** object. So the question now is *How to search for "tooltip" in **tab**?*

I used the following code to see the contents of the above-mentioned objects:
`alert(JSON.stringify(tab, null, 4));`
`alert(JSON.stringify(document, null, 4));`

Comment: I wonder what `alert(element);` shows.  Maybe this code isn't in running in the actual page and some other element is being found.

Comment: Thanks user212514, it's a good guess. It turned out that **element** contains `null`.

Comment: It also turned out that **document** contains the __generated_background_page.html_, and not my page in question. And the actual page I need is contained in **tab** object. So the question now is _How to search in **tab**?_
`tab.getElementById(...)` returns an error.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it is onclick not onclicked

```
chrome.browserAction.onClick.addListener
(
  function(tab)
  {
    var element = document.getElementById('tooltip');
    alert(element.innerText);
  }
);
```

Comment: Hardly so :(
Firstly, because, like I said ```alert("some text");``` works fine in the same context.
And secondly, the correct form seems to be onClicked https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageAction#event-onClicked Anyway, I gave it a try :)

Comment: big oof, idk then

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have found a solution. I'm not sure if it's the most elegant one, but still it works.

I created a second script named **script2.js** and refer to it from **script1.js**.

Below is the contents of **script1.js** which is executed when I click the extension's button in the toolbar of the browser:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab){
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "script2.js"});
});
```

**script1.js** calls **script2.js** which contains the main code:

```
var element = document.getElementById('tooltip');
if(element != null) alert(element.innerText);
else alert('element is null');
```